# Taylor exercise

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let $f\in C^\infty$

$\exists L>0: \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n\geq 1$
$$|f^{(n)}(x)| \le L,$$

Let $$f(0)=0$$
Prove that $$f(x)=0$$

I using Taylor series but the rest remains and do not know how to eliminate it.

Taylor:
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)(x-0)+\frac {f''(0)}{2}(x-0)^2+o_2(x-o)$$

Comment: Show the details of your work. I don't know what you mean by "the rest remains," but if you wrote out your equations it would probably be easy to see.

Comment: @DavidK This question was asked already today and is already false, take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for example.

Comment: Duplicate. question not well asked !

Comment: @SimpleArt I just looked at the format of the question and decided if the asker would not bother to give details, I would not bother to think about the question. And the evidence shows I didn't think about it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a false result.

Take for instance

$$f\colon x\mapsto \sin(x).$$

You have:

- $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$,
- $\vert f^{(n)}\vert\leqslant 1$,
- $f(0)=0$.

But obviously $f(x)\ne 0$ if $x\notin \pi\mathbb Z$.